# NullPointerException when using Google maps, android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using Google maps in my android code, I want to get the address of my location using "Geocoder" class.

this is the code I am using

```
Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but I am getting a NullPointerException at this line:

```
addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);
```

here is the full code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements LocationListener {


    private TextView cityText;
    private TextView condDescr;
    private TextView temp;
    private TextView press;
    private TextView windSpeed;
    private TextView windDeg;

    private TextView hum;
    private ImageView imgView;
    Geocoder geocoder;
    String bestProvider;
    List<Address> user = null;
    double lat;
    double lng;
   public static String resultStr;
    private String latituteField;
    private String longitudeField;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;
    public String cityName;
    public Location loc;
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location loc) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         String longitude = "Longitude: " +loc.getLongitude();  
        //  Log.v(TAG, longitude);
            String latitude = "Latitude: " +loc.getLatitude();
            //Log.v(TAG, latitude);
    //String 
        cityName=null;                
          Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(),   
       Locale.getDefault());               
          List<Address>  addresses;    
          try {    
          addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc  
       .getLongitude(), 1);    
          if (addresses.size() > 0)    
             System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());    
             cityName=addresses.get(0).getLocality();    
            } catch (IOException e) {              
            e.printStackTrace();    
          }   

          String s = longitude+"\n"+latitude +  
       "\n\nMy Currrent City is: "+cityName;  
              // editLocation.setText(s);  
            }  




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("hi","hi");


        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Log.d("addresses",addresses.toString());

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
        // default
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        android.location.Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        // Initialize the location fields
        if (location != null) {
          System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
          onLocationChanged(location);
        } else {
             System.out.println("location not available");

        }

    //  String city ="lat=%f&lon=%f,"  

        /////////////////////////
        cityText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cityText);
        condDescr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.condDescr);
        temp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temp);
        hum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hum);
        press = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.press);
        windSpeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.windSpeed);
        windDeg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.windDeg);
        imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.condIcon);

        JSONWeatherTask task = new JSONWeatherTask();
        //task.execute(new String[]{city});
        task.execute(new String[]{cityName});
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    private class JSONWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Weather> {

        @Override
        protected Weather doInBackground(String... params) {
            Weather weather = new Weather();
            String data = ( (new WeatherHttpClient()).getWeatherData(params[0]));

            try {
                weather = JSONWeatherParser.getWeather(data);

                // Let's retrieve the icon
                weather.iconData = ( (new WeatherHttpClient()).getImage(weather.currentCondition.getIcon()));

            } catch (JSONException e) {             
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return weather;

    }





    @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Weather weather) {         
            super.onPostExecute(weather);

            if (weather.iconData != null && weather.iconData.length > 0) {
                Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(weather.iconData, 0, weather.iconData.length); 
                imgView.setImageBitmap(img);
            }

            cityText.setText(weather.location.getCity() + "," + weather.location.getCountry());
            condDescr.setText(weather.currentCondition.getCondition() + "(" + weather.currentCondition.getDescr() + ")");
            temp.setText("" + Math.round((weather.temperature.getTemp() - 275.15)) + "°C");
            hum.setText("" + weather.currentCondition.getHumidity() + "%");
            press.setText("" + weather.currentCondition.getPressure() + " hPa");
            windSpeed.setText("" + weather.wind.getSpeed() + " mps");
            windDeg.setText("" + weather.wind.getDeg() + "°");

        }







  }


    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }






}
```

and this is the logCat:

```
11-09 04:30:55.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1868): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-09 04:30:55.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1868): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.survivingwithandroid.weatherapp/com.survivingwithandroid.weatherapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-09 04:30:55.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1868):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
11-09 04:30:55.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1868):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
11-09 04:30:55.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1868):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-09 04:30:55.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1868):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
11-09 04:30:55.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1868):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-09 04:30:55.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1868):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-09 04:30:55.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1868):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-09 04:30:55.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1868):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-09 04:30:55.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1868):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-09 04:30:55.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1868):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-09 04:30:55.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1868):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-09 04:30:55.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1868):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-09 04:30:55.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1868): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-09 04:30:55.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1868):     at com.survivingwithandroid.weatherapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:127)
11-09 04:30:55.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1868):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
11-09 04:30:55.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1868):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-09 04:30:55.723: E/AndroidRuntime(1868):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
```

Comment: location is null i think so please post your relevant code...

Comment: i think network is issue ? hv u added permissions?

Comment: try to use static location for test..If it will get success then there is null location in your case..

Comment: @ruaa.brkat you haven't initialized your location object

Comment: I just would like to notify you that you will encounter the problem I described if your seeking to receive an address from just the geocoder from the getFromLocation() method and suggest you incorporate JsonObject as well for retrieving the address. Just looking out for prior errors to occur in the future :]

Comment: I solved the exception, but now I am getting a very wrong results!! it tells me that I am in India!!

Comment: instance field 'loc' is null , that is why you get NPE (Null Pointer Exception). It is not yet assigned with 'Location' Object, may be  because of 'onLocationChanged' method should not have been called.

Comment: @Jayasagar the method should be called!!

Answer (score 0):

I identified another problem which will occur with some devices with the code your using and it is regarding the one line as well which uses the getFromLocation method. Unfortunately that is a bug related to the android OS which is related to the updated Google play services, mostly found in 4.1.X devices.. The only real solution is to reboot the phone and run the app again to enable geocodsr. Your getFromLocation() method is going to return in some cases an error of service not available. This is not really a solution but rather the only workaround regarding the geocoder. I did countless hours of research trying to solve this problem for myself because it would work on some phones and not on others, and only found that rebooting the phone will enable it but over time the error will show up thus requiring the user to reboot again.

That is inconvenient so instead do a try catch statement and if the geocoder doesn't work use a JSONobject. Read post #13 for a workaround with JSONObject.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38009
Best of luck.

Comment: I solved the exception, but now I am getting a very wrong results!!
it tells me that I am in India!!

Comment: I just changed this line 

'String s = longitude+"\n"+latitude +    "\n\nMy Currrent City is: "+cityName;'
  
to this line :
   'String s=cityName;'

Comment: If it tells you you're in India, and you're somewhere else, you probably switched lat with lng ;)

Comment: Hahaha looks like Michael hit it spot on.

Comment: @MichałK I don't think that is the problem, since the longitude and latitude of my location is totally different of India, even when switching longitude and latitude!!

Comment: @ChallengeAccepted I don't think that is the problem, since the longitude and latitude of my location is totally different of India, even when switching longitude and latitude!!

Comment: @ruaa.brkat ensure that this is done on a device and not an emulator. Double check it refreshs your method and your GPS object uses getLastKnownLocation repeatedly to give you the latest measurement. If your receiving outrageous addresses it might be either you declared a default instant to be used within your code or simply that you didn't refresh and allow the GPS object enough time to get a more accurate location. It can take a few seconds to get an accurate location

Comment: @ChallengeAccepted on the simulator I got Mumbai,India. On my device the application crashes

Comment: @ruaa.brkat the emulator isn't going to give you the right location because its being EMULATED. It has fixed setting, you set its longitude and latitude. Also if it works on the emulator but not your device, means that your device is returning a null value and that might be because of the reason I explained in my answer. Try rebooting your phone and then running your application on your device again.

Comment: @ruaa.brkat Here is an example of what I mean emulated on the device and why your getting India; because its set to some default value already in the emulation settings. See this post.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6264577/1371041