# Getting present Latitude and Longitude values in android

Tags: android

**What i am trying to do**:: To log the current latitude and longitude values in a Log

**What i have done** :: I have pushed the Coordinators to Emulator in android

**What i am not able to do** :: I am not able to see the log values in output

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener ll = new Mylocationlistener();

        boolean isGPS = lm
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // If GPS is not enable then it will be on
        if(!isGPS)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
            intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }

        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
    }
    private class Mylocationlistener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLatitude() + "");
                Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLongitude() + "");
                float speed = location.getSpeed();
                double altitude = location.getAltitude();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Latitude = "+
                        location.getLatitude() + "" +"Longitude = "+ location.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Log.d("---Latitude - Log ",""+location.getLatitude());
                Log.d("---Latitude - Log ",""+location.getLongitude());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }
}
```

**Update** 
**manifest**::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.presentcityname"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.presentcityname.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: where are you running it??

Comment: @user3243147 ....I am running it in emulator

Comment: ok
run it on real device

Comment: Put one more log inside onLoactaionChanged() just top of the if(location!=null) to track whether this call back gets triggerd or not when feeding location .And how you are pushing values? through emulator control's Manual option ?

Comment: @Mohan Raj ... Yes through emulator control's Manual option

Comment: @user3243147 .... I dont have a real device so i am trying to get from emulator .... can you point me to any other sample code to achieve this

Comment: How you add this permission in manifest ?     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
You can try with emulator control it self.

Comment: Ok
Just put an other toast w/o lat n lng, just wanna to check

Comment: n imp part did you add permissions??

Comment: @user3243147 ..& Mohan Raj.. Please Check the updated question i have posted the manifest

Comment: ok
did you put an other toast or log w/o lat lng? 
do you having internet connection in your emulator??

Comment: @ user3243147 ........ Sorry it was my mistake .... I had posted wrong manifest ... noe updated it .... Giving permission in manifest was the problem .... <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> .... post it as answer ill accept it :)

Comment: good !
getting your lat lng :)

Answer (score 1):

`onLocationChanged(Location location)` in this method you will get location always null if you are running the application in emulator.

Comment: incorrect, if he's passing the loc through DDMS , it should work fine

Comment: Yes ! .... I have passed the location through DDMS ! ... Is there any other way to get the values ..... any other examples ?

Comment: @user2450263 we don't know how he is passing the location...if he puts a log in that method we can know that is null or not..

Comment: @Casper if you haven't already referred to [Loc using DDMS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264485/android-get-latitude-and-longitude-on-emulator-of-android?rq=1)  , pls do and make sure you are passing it correctly

Comment: @user2450263.... I have refered the exact same posting and code i have taken from the post you suggested